# How can I create this rock from it's image in Blender?

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image: Rock]

Is there a way to create 3D model which looks exactly the same as the image?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you really want to create this image almost identical then you should look at photoscanning. However, because this does not appear as a real rock it looks like your just going to have to put in the hours and just model it by hand until you get the rock itself. Just start by modelling the basic shape of the rock then start detailing and then finally add your Texture and Ground Terrain.
And then Viola.

Comment: where can i find the tutorial?

Comment: I would suggest Going to Blender Guru's Youtube channel and checking out his mars tutorials as he shows you how he does his. If this answers your Question please tick the arrow so that others know it has been answered.

Comment: Is it essential to have this rock as a 3D object?  You couldn't save a lot of work and just cut it out in GIMP?  Place that on an alpha layer and texture a 2D plane with it?  If you're not moving the camera around it, it would be hard to tell the difference.

Comment: Yes but, shading/Lighting will look horrible with the rock.  3d is an actual object